# Proper way to end a thread in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a worker `Thread` with a `Handler` associated with it. The `Handler` receives `Message`s and perform some operations in the worker `Thread`. I would like to "stop" the `Thread` in `onPause()` of my `Activity`. In the `onPause()` method of my `Activity`, i send a quit message to my `Handler` so that my worker `Thread` will break out of `Looper.loop()` and return from `run()`.

1. Is this the correct way to stop a `Thread`? If not, how should it be done?
2. I have seen code examples calling `t1.join()` from the main `Thread` where t1 is their worker `Thread`.

   - What is the purpose of `join()`?
   - Do i need to do a `join()` in my example?

My worker `Thread`:

```
class WorkerThread extends Thread {
    private static final int QUIT = -1;
    public Handler mHandler;

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        mHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // do stuff

                if(msg.what == QUIT){
                    Looper.myLooper().quit();
                }

                // do stuff
            }
        };

        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked on android but in java a thread can be stopped in following ways -

1. Use a volatile Boolean flag - Use this flag in loop(while(flag)). Which keeps running till the flag is true. If you want to stop thread set flag to false.
2. Checking for interrupt flag- You have static Boolean method in thread class as Thread.interrupted() which checks for interrupt flag. You can interrupt a waiting thread by calling Thread.interrupt().

Join() method - the Join method makes the current thread to wait for a thread to die. This is used in the case when you have some logic which is to be executed only after a thread completes its execution. So you can't use join to stop a thread but make a thread to wait for another thread completion.

Hope it helps. Thanks